# Three Delta Function Potential -- Possible Nodes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

Let us say you have a potential function of the following form:

$$V(x) = -V_o a \sum_{n = -1}^{1} \delta(x-na)$$

where $V_o > 0, a>0$

I am trying to figure out the number of possible nodes that can be in regions $(1)$ $x > a$ and $(2)$ $0 < x < a$. Obviously, we are talking about bound states, so $E < 0$. in both regions the time-independent schodinger equation reduces to:

$$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \partial^2_x\phi(x) =E\phi(x)$$

Which implies $\partial^2_x (\phi) \phi > 0$. A node condition such that $\phi(x_0) = 0$ would not be possible ... however, I am unable to build a similar argument for (2)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in both regions the time-independent schodinger equation reduces to:
>
> $$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \partial^2_x\phi(x) =E\phi(x)$$
>
> Which implies $\partial^2_x (\phi) \phi > 0$.

The conclusion is false. The function $\phi(x) = \sinh(x)$ satisfies this equation (modulo choosing appropriate values for the constants) and it does have a node.

Comment: If the condition is not always true, then the left hand side will have the opposite sign to the right ... $\sinh^2(x) \ge 0$ so are you trying to say that $\partial_x^2(\phi) \phi \ge 0$ is the correct condition?

Comment: You have derived that $\partial^2_x (\phi) \phi \propto \phi(x)^2$, and the only thing that follows is that $\phi^2\geq0$ if $\phi$ is real. There are no grounds to conclude strict positivity here.

Comment: What about the fact that $E$ must be negative?